# sql combine two queries in one and SORT BY

Tags: sql, sqlite, sorting, multi-query

I have a large table and I've built two queries to first query the first 2 columns and then
the other columns. My intention obviously to put first 2 columns data on top then append
the other columns's data below.  Here is the query.

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE A LIKE 'query%' OR G LIKE 'query%' ORDER BY LENGTH(A) )
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE I LIKE 'query' OR J LIKE 'query' LIMIT 15)
```

This works okay but it is way too slow. Is there any way I can make it faster. Because I
feel like I am making unnecessary SELECTS (4).
Maybe I can make something like (I saw this suggestion here on Stackoverflow):

```
SELECT  * 
FROM 
        (
            SELECT *, 1 sortby FROM TABLE_A 
            UNION ALL 
            SELECT *, 2 sortby FROM TABLE_B
        ) dum
ORDER   BY sortby
```

But I have no idea how to do it for my case.

Thanks alot.

Comment: Why do you need the results from the first query on top of those from the second query?

Comment: It is a technical dictionary and  the words on the first columns are more important to show first. Words from the columns afterwards, are less important.

Comment: Remove like if you need exact results,use= `WHERE I ='query' OR J ='query'`

Comment: The query works as I need it to, I'm looking to make it lighter if possible.

Comment: Do you have any indexes on the A/G/I/J columns? Are they case-insensitive?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you´re right. There is 2 un-needed selects in your query.
This would work, but I doubt that it would be any better performance.

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE A LIKE 'query%' OR G LIKE 'query%' 
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE I LIKE 'query' OR J LIKE 'query' LIMIT 15
ORDER BY LENGTH(A)
```

Comment: ORDER BY clause should come after UNION ALL not before

Comment: OK, Just add the "ORDER BY LENGTH(A)" to the last line (after the last select).

Answer (score -1):

Have you try this :

```
Select m1.A,m2.I from (SELECT A FROM mytable m1 WHERE A LIKE 'query%' OR G LIKE 'query%'

ORDER BY LENGTH(A)

 UNION ALL

SELECT I FROM mytable m2 WHERE I LIKE 'query' OR J LIKE 'query' LIMIT 15))
ORDER BY m1.A,m2.I
```